# Hibernate how does not generate unique index

Tags: java, hibernate

Generated Table **question_list_sent** with **question_id** field - this field  with **unique** index. How annotated this field to be **normal instead of unique**.

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "question_list")
public class QuestionList implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private User owner;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "question_list_sent",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "question_list_id",unique = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "question_id",unique = false)}
    )
    private List<Question> sent;
```

Comment: Because you've annotated id with `@Id` its going to be unique. Primary keys have to be unique by definition.

Comment: I dont understend why, when i try to add question to question_list_sent table. 
One object add good. Second object i had sql error like Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_ec3ea7kgh4fb1k0oq04m7gb69' , when i switch question_id in question_list_sent table from unique to normal, all good. why?

Answer (score 0):

Your JoinTable is OneToMany, which means that one QuestionList can have multiple Questions, but each Question only has one QuestionList.  To remove the unique constraint, make your JoinTable ManyToMany.